# Is there any way to sync audio with text. I have to highlight text "word by word" for audio file

Tags: objective-c

Is there any way to sync audio with text. I have to highlight text "word by word" for audio file. I have no idea on how to begin with this. I have not yet worked on Audio files. Which View (UITextView or UIWebView) should i use to display my text for the implementation of this feature ? I'm building this as an iPad Book reading App.
All suggestions are welcome.
 
- Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open file format [LRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_%28file_format%29) which specifies time and lyrics for audio files. You can adopt this format to easily into your application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing a voice recognition software such as [PolitePix OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#) then as each word is recognized change the color of it in your app.  OpenEars will only recognize words specified so it is a great option for children's stories.